# How to use a variable inside eval function from input variable Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile where I have to define a variable using a generic function where a parameter is another variable. Here is my code :

```
testX :
        @read -p "Enter Size Stack : " REP; \
        $(eval ARG=$(shell shuf -i 0-50 -n $$REP))
        echo $(ARG)
```

The problem is that **shuf** do not recognize **$$REP**.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You haven't shown us [enough of your makefile to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In particular, we don't know how you assigned a value to `REP`, nor *how you know* that `shuf` not recognizing `REP` is the problem. But I see two problems:

Comment: 1) You used a backslash to continue the first line of the recipe into the second, but you did not use one to continue the second line into the third. This means that the third line is a separate command. In a recipe, each line executes in its own subshell; the first command can assign a value to `ARG`, but then it terminates and the value dies with it. When the second command (`echo $(ARG)`) executes, it has no memory of the earlier assignment. 2) `eval` doesn't work the way you think it does, and you are mixing shell syntax and Make syntax in a way that is almost certain to fail.

Comment: Since `$(ARG)` is a make variable, the backslash stuff is not needed actually.  All of this is expanded and resolved before any shell invocation happens.

Comment: As I explained in my answer, this entire approach is fatally flawed because that's just not how expansion works in make.  You must abandon it and trying to "make it work" can't succeed.

Comment: The following comment has already been answered by Madscientist just above.

Comment: @Beta I can't add a backslash at the second line otherwise I get the following error "/bin/sh: 2: Syntax error: ";" unexpected"
I think that I don't very well understand how eval works.
If I use this code without backslash at the second line I can get the output of **$(ARG)**
`testX :  $(NAME)
  @read -p "Enter Size Stack : " REP; \
   $(eval ARG=$(shell shuf -i 0-50 -n 3))
  @echo $(ARG); \
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this.  Make recipe commands are invoked in shells, and shells have their own variables which exist only in those shells.  Once the shell exits, those variables are gone.  You can't use them in subsequent shells.

Also, make will expand all make variables and functions *first* before it runs any shells.  So by the time make runs the shell script that performs the `read`, the `eval` is already run, and the make variable `ARG` is already expanded.

In any event, it's very unusual and not really a good idea to ask for input inside a make recipe.  That's just not how make is designed to work.  Better is to use a command line variable:

```
$ cat Makefile
testX :
        ARG=$$(shuf -i 0-50 -n $(SIZE)) ; \
        echo $$ARG

$ make SIZE=50
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer MadScientist.
So can I define the value of **SIZE** directly as an argument ? ($make SIZE = 50)

Comment: Yes it's good it works !
I didn't know that you could set the value of a variable directly as an argument.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: It's discussed in the GNU make manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding.html